# unexpected token < in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This is my js file in this i'm having an unexpected token < error i have verified the code from jshint there was nothing that could resolve the issue.

i have tried putting the js in different file and also tried putting in same file as html but nothing worked out the error still there

```
function ajax() {
  var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return XMLHttpRequestObject;
}

function login() {
  var wait = document.getElementById('wait-img').style;
  wait.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
  var email = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  if (email === '' || password === '') {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Please fill out all details';
    wait.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
    return;
  }
  var data = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&x=login";
  var xml = ajax();
  if (xml) {
    xml.open("POST", "login1.php");
    xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
        var reply = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
        if (reply == 'failure') {
          document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Email or password is incorrect';
        } else
          window.location = 'profile.php?id=' + reply;
        wait.style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
      }
    };
    xml.send(data);
  }
}

function signup() {
  var wait = document.getElementById('wait-img').style;
  wait.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('psswd').value;
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  var confirm = document.getElementById('confirm').value;
  if (email === '' || password === '' || phone === '' || confirm === '') {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Please fill out all details';
    wait.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
    return;
  }
  if (password != confirm) {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Password did not match';
    wait.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
    return;
  }
  var data = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&phone=" + phone + "&x=signup";
  var xml = ajax();
  if (xml) {
    xml.open("POST", "signup.php");
    xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
        var reply = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
        if (reply == 'failure') {
          document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Sorry something went wrong';
        } else
          window.location = 'profile.php?id=' + reply;
        wait.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
      }

    };
    xml.send(data);
  }
}
```

Update: error is on line no 41 of this file.

Comment: where you see this error? seems like someone your `xml.responseText` not a json, and you have this error when try parse it

Comment: please post the output of login1.php or signup.php, when you POST to it. Either from the browser's console's network tab or when you try to post to them from a regular form

Comment: nobody will count 41 lines in this question! Please add a comment to the previous line: `// THE ERROR IS IN THE NEXT LINE:` Also add `console.log(xml.responseText);` in the 1st line of onreadystatechange callbacks, and show us the output

Comment: thanks guys i figured it out it was little typo in my php file

Answer (score 2):

The error must be in the JSON file you are importing(in the `JSON.parse(xml.responseText);`

Use try-catch to make sure that the imported file is of correct JSON Syntax.

`try{
    var reply=JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
} catch(e){
    console.log(e,xml.responseText)
}`

This will help you debug the error.